# Max Players Per Day Group by Host

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, unique, concatenation

Having a little trouble with my MySQL query

Here's my structure:

```
select * from servers group by host;


+-----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id  | host                 | players | time                |
+-----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
|   1 | 28.167.243.83:27035  |       3 | 2016-12-12 21:03:33 |
|   3 | 78.17.183.116:27015  |      10 | 2016-12-12 21:03:33 |
|  63 | 208.147.243.91:27025 |       1 | 2016-12-12 21:56:01 |
| 115 | 208.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:30:02 |
| 118 | 206.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:32:02 |
| 121 | 204.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:34:01 |
| 124 | 203.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:36:01 |
| 127 | 202.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:38:01 |
| 130 | 201.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:40:01 |
| 133 | 208.147.243.83:27035 |       2 | 2016-12-12 22:42:02 |
+-----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

The result keeps going, for there's a new entry every 5 minutes for each host.

I want it to look like this:

[image: Example Output]

Except the second column should look like this:

```
unique date;max players on that unique date
```

And delimited by commas for each unique date to max players set

**How would I achieve this through a query?**

Screenshot query:

```
SELECT host, TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) * 1000, ',', players) ORDER BY `time` ASC SEPARATOR ';')) AS datapoints FROM servers where `time` between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 8 WEEK) and now() GROUP BY `host`
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1350d

Comment: OK, but what is the question?

Comment: @trailmax How would I achieve this through a query?

Comment: @RumbleFrog do you want more than one entry per day?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Per host? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    `host`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`day`,';',`max_players`)) as `info`
FROM (SELECT
        `host`,
        DATE_FORMAT(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as `day`,
        MAX(`players`) as `max_players`
    FROM `so_test_servers`
    GROUP BY `host`, `day`) as A
GROUP BY `host`
```

Comment: It sorta works, how can I group concat this to match the example screenshot?

Comment: Thanks it worked, I cannot upvote unfortunately (not enough rep). My final solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1350d/10

Answer (score 0):

As you want the columns concatenated by comma, you can write the `GROUP BY` query and wrap it into another query, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.host, CONCAT(a.`date`, ';', a.max_players)
FROM (
 SELECT 
     `host`,
     DATE_FORMAT(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as `date`,
     MAX(`players`) as 'max_players'
 FROM servers
 GROUP BY host, `date`
) a;
```

Comment: What's the `a` on the end for

Comment: It's an alias for inner table defined in `FROM`.

Comment: Would I use group concat, to use comma to delimit like the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap it into `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the required result.